# Fetching Complex User Defined SQL Type from a Stored Procedure in Spring, using Spring JDBCTemplate and StoredProcedure API

Tags: sql, oracle, spring, stored-procedures, jdbctemplate

I am facing difficulty while fetching Complex Object Type from Oracle to Java.

I am using Spring JDBCTemplate and Spring StoredProcedure.

At the Oracle end I have used a function which return an OBJECT(UNIT)which consists of TABLE(DIVISION_TAB) of an OBJECT(DIVISION) which itself consists of a TABLE(EMPLOYEE_TAB) of another OBJECT(EMPLOYEE).

These types are defined as below:

```
create or replace TYPE UNIT AS OBJECT 
( 
  UNIT_ID        NUMBER(38),
  UNIT_NAME      VARCHAR(50),
  DIVIVSION_LIST DIVIVSION_TAB
)

create or replace
TYPE DIVISION_TAB
AS TABLE OF DIVISION

create or replace
TYPE DIVISION AS OBJECT 
( 
  DIV_ID        NUMBER(38),
  DIV_NAME      VARCHAR(50),
  DIV_STATUS    NUMBER(38),
  EMPLOYEE_LIST EMPLOYEE_TAB
)

create or replace
TYPE EMPLOYEE_TAB
AS TABLE OF EMPLOYEE

create or replace
    TYPE EMPLOYEE AS OBJECT 
    ( 
      EMP_ID        NUMBER(38),
      EMP_NAME      VARCHAR(50),
      EMP_STATUS    NUMBER(38),
      EMP_SAL       NUMBER(20),
    )
```

Function at Database level return me an SQL Object of UNIT, which I am using in the following way while retrieving it in Java.

```
declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("UNIT", OracleTypes.STRUCT, "UNIT",new SqlReturnType() {
         public Object getTypeValue(CallableStatement callableStatement, int colIndx, int sqlType, String typeName) 
            throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = callableStatement.getConnection();

        Map<String, Class<?>> typeMap = connection.getTypeMap();
        typeMap.put("UNIT", Unit.class);
        typeMap.put("DIVISION_TAB", java.sql.Array.class);
        typeMap.put("DIVISION", Division.class);
        typeMap.put("EMPLOYEE_TAB", java.sql.Array.class);
        typeMap.put("EMPLOYEE", Employee.class);

        STRUCT struct = (STRUCT)callableStatement.getObject(colIndx);
        Object[] attr = struct.getAttributes();
        return attr;
        }
    }));
```

PROBLEM::::

When I am debugging Object[] returned by SqlReturnType() method then I am able to fetch the details like UNIT_ID and UNIT_NAME but on the 3rd attribute i.e of type oracle.sql.ARRAY, when I am performing the following operation :

```
        ARRAY array = (ARRAY)attr[3];
    Object[] objects =  (Object[])((ARRAY)attr[3]).getArray();
```

it throws SQL Internat Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved. Just a simple mistake. The code is perfectly correct, I just missed giving grant to the TYPES I have defined.